# Create Table using PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to create a table using PostgreSQL. The code above is correctly authenticating. The problem I'm facing now is how to correctly create the table 'devices' and write data to it.

```
const Sequelize =  require('sequelize');
const env = require('./config');

sequelize =  new Sequelize({
    database: '******',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    username: '********',
    password: '******',
    host: '********',
    port: 3211
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
console.log("Connected to DB");
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
})

function insertIntoPostgres(filename, data) {

var fileToCreate = 
`/${env.azurePG.data_store_pg.folder}/${filename}.json`;
var options = {
    streamContents: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data))

}

filesystemClient.fileSystem.create(env.azurePG.data_store_pg.account_name_pg, fileToCreate, options)
    .then(res => {})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("error inserting into postgres: ", err);
    });
};
// Export the above methods
module.exports = {
insertIntoPostgres
}
```

Here is the part of my code that I think is wrong from the above code:

```
filesystemClient.fileSystem.create(env.azurePG.data_store_pg.account_name_pg, fileToCreate, options)
.then(res => {})
.catch(err => {
    console.log("error inserting into postgres: ", err);
});
};
```

my config.js

```
module.exports = {
PGDATABASE : "******",
PGPORT : 3211,
azurePG : {
  PGUSER : "*******",
  PGHOST : "********",
  PGPASSWORD : "*******",
  data_store_pg : {
    account_name_pg : "********",
    folder : "devices"
  }
}
};
```

Any ideas on where is the problem?

Comment: Nothing in that code looks anything at all like a `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement.

Comment: I see that I'm doing it wrong. How do I populate an existent table correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the table first, then run your code to populate the table. I would take a look at the data set you're working with to get an idea of the field names and data types and then run something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE devices(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    otherfield TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I'm not sure if you're trying to build a full automated cycle of creating a table and populating it, but you could just hop on over to postgres and run the create table code in the terminal or whatever database management tool you're using. After the table is created, you should be table to run the below code to verify it's been created correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM devices
```

It should come back with an empty table with all the columns you specified. If all that is good to go, run your code that populates the table. Should work fine.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to create one table called "Devices" and populate it all together. After it will have to populate a existent table which looks like this:                      
  devices_test(
    _id character(50),
    _ts bigint,
    battery numeric(6,4),
    home_id character(50),
    humidity numeric(6,4),
    light numeric(6,4),
    sound numeric(6,4),
    temperature numeric(6,4),
    datetime timestamp
);

Comment: I see that I'm doing it wrong. How do I populate an existent table correctly?